# Magento 2 - The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only (Even though folder has 777)

Tags: magento2, permissions, compile

I get "*The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only*" during **setup:di:compile** even though the folder has **777** permission.

I even tried with **sudo**, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command from CLI.

> sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/

Comment: It is already set as 777, both var and generated.

Comment: Does that set properly? or it reset automatically when site is load on frontend?

Answer (score 0):

Try below setps and check.

> rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ var/{cache,composer_home,page_cache,view_preprocesseds,di} generated/*

> sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

> sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile

> sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove **generated** directory with the root user.

   `sudo rm -rf generated`
2. **Then switch to the Web server user** (typically, it is www-data)
3. Finally, compile code:

   `bin/magento setup:di:compile`